# Fragment and Activity having separate Toolbars is not working as Activity toolbar is always shown instead

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

What I am trying to achieve is to add a Toolbar to my Fragment UI when my Activity also has a bar that is NOT shown inside the fragment. Basically, how can my Activity and Fragment(s) have their own toolbar?

This is my code in my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

And here is my code in my fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) mView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    return mView;
}
```

What I get is that when I create the toolbar in my Fragment, the toolbar is the toolbar from the activity. What I want to do is I want the fragment to have it's separate toolbar from it's parent Activity.

Here are a few things that I can think of which are definitely not ideal:

1. Make the fragment an activity.
2. Simulate as if I have created a toolbar but simply have the Fragment toolbar defined as a UI element that I have pieced together myself.
3. Somehow edit the parent Activity's toolbar to make it specific to the fragment, and then somehow redraw the Activity toolbar? This seems weird and I am not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: Don't set toolbar in your fragment

Comment: @AbhayBohra, sure, but what would be the solution to the problem? I still need to provide that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 toolbars in one activity is not advisable since it'll look really bad.

with `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`
you're replacing the activities toolbar with the one that you're defined in the fragment's layout file.

I would suggest you to use fragment specific actions for the toolbar when the fragment is visible on the screen and change it's behavior by accessing the content of the toolbar by

```
Toolbar mToolbar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

now use the mToolbar to change the actions

Comment: Sure, but that also means that the toolbar will stay changed, per the Fragment changes, once the fragments completes? Hence, now if I replace this fragment with another where the original toolbar is needed, I need to completely re-set the toolbar to the original state because that toolbar has been changed by the first fragment.

Comment: Not completely... Just create a method in the activity to reinitialise the toolbar and call it from the fragment's `onDestroy` method

Comment: I just switched to an activity instead of a fragment. I think it may have worked better anyway so I just went with that. Thanks for the input.